# Can't install Fiona in OSGeo4W Shell on Windows 10

Tags: python, fiona, osgeo4w

When trying to install "Fiona‑1.8.20‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl" in the OSGeo4W Shell I get the following errors:

```
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp(3198): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge\x94ffnet werden: "cpl_port.h": No such file or directory
extensions/gdal_array_wrap.cpp(3144): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge\x94ffnet werden: "gdal.h": No such file or directory
extensions/gnm_wrap.cpp(3135): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge\x94ffnet werden: "gdal.h": No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I use python 3.9.5 and Windows 10.

Comment: I think you will need to add the gdal-dev (or some similar name) package via the installer

Comment: That has worked indeed. However, now when im trying to import fiona in Jupyter Notebook it throws an Attribute Error:
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)
So far I haven't found a solution for this.
In the _loading.py file I find this comment:
# With Python >= 3.8 on Windows directories in PATH are not automatically
# searched for DLL dependencies and must be added manually with
# os.add_dll_directory.
# see https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/851
Yet I don't really know what to do with it